# Get all TRUE Values Property Name from PSObject

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a PSObject which looks like that:

```
Name                 : Full Name
givenname            : Full
surname              : Name
emailaddress         : email@domain.com
Direct               : xxx
Mobile               : xxx
Prop1                : TRUE
Prop2                : TRUE
Prop3                : TRUE
Prop4                : TRUE
Prop5                : TRUE
Prop6                : TRUE
Prop7                :
Prop8                :
```

I want to get all the property names that have a `TRUE` value.

I can get this info on that way:

```
$Props = $Object | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty |
         Select -ExpandProperty Name
$temp = @()
foreach ($prop in $Props) {
    if ($Object.$Prop -eq $true) {
        $temp += $prop
    }
}
```

But I wonder if there's a better/easier method.

Comment: This Is not the same question, nor answer the question, I need to get only the true values without using loop, that was the question from the first place(see my example) I looking for other methods... thanks

Comment: The first answer in the linked question is probably the best answer. But you still have to add an if or where-test to find the ones with true-value. Adding the test itself is not worth having a 99% duplicate question.

Comment: @JustCurious As a matter of fact the question *is* the same: how to enumerate the properties of an object. And the accepted answer is, at least to my knowledge, the best way to do it.

Comment: ok guys, that's all I wanted to know, if this is the best approach or if there's another method, if it's the best you know, it's enough. thanks

Comment: $Object.PSObject.Properties | ? { $_.Value -eq $true } | % { $_.Name }

Comment: @MarcKellerman thanks, you can add it as answer...

Comment: The approach is essentially the same, just using `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` instead of `foreach` and `if`.

Comment: @JustCurious I can't, the question has been closed.